# Making minimal modifications to fix code

Tags: discussion, code-golf, code-challenge

This is bugging the hell out of me. I could have sworn I had seen the challenge here: http://golf.shinh.org/all.rb a while back, but I've just gone through all **500** of those challenges and none of them are what I'm looking for.

The challenge I remember was as follows. There was a short snippet (about 10 or so lines) of code (javascript I believe) and the object was to modify the code to produce a certain output. There were a few rules that specified the types of changes that could be made. If memory serves they were to add one character, change two characters, or delete one character. If not those, then something similar. The problem had 3 or 4 solutions.

I'm aware that my description is quite vague, especially considering that I'm looking for something very specific, but I was also hoping that if not this exact challenge, someone could point me to something similar. That is, something where you have to make a couple changes to make some code work.

Comment: I remember such a challenge, but don't know where to find it.

Comment: I believe I know what you are looking for. Check my puzzle here it is similar: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8554/m3ph1st0ss-programming-puzzle-3-c-easy-bug.

Answer (score 1):

I found it by searching for

> +add +delete

Here [Conversion to palindrome with minimal points used](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4754/conversion-to-palindrome-with-minimal-points-used) is such a challenge in (C++/C#).

Somehow the system transforms my answer automatically into a comment - seems to think, quality = quantity.

Comment: That seems a bit different from what the OP describes; specifically "the object was to modify _the code_" (emphasis mine).

Comment: I guess you're right, but since he isn't sure, it maybe has been something similar, only? Or maybe it was only a proposal here at Meta?

Comment: Or it was a old question on SE?

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to what you describe that I remember seeing here is [Write a program that always outputs "2012" - even if it's modified!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4486/write-a-program-that-always-outputs-2012-even-if-its-modified).  However, that was about writing a program that *can't* be minimally modified to change its output.