# What's up with Community♦ in Meta?

Tags: support, meta

I have been seeing [this question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/483/3862) bumped to the top of the active list in Meta, showing in the list as having been modified by [Community♦](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community). However, when I look into it, I see no changes were made to the question itself, any of the answers, or any of the comments.

I haven't paid too much attention, but I sort of recall seeing the same on other questions in the past as well ([this one I think](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/465/3862)), but I'm not sure of which questions get it or how often.

So, why does this keep bumping? Is this a bug or is it actually something happening behind the scenes that I just have the privs to see?

Comment: It's funny how `Community♦` edited this question too :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the about me box in user Community♦'s profile. It says

> Hi, I'm not really a person.
>
> I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!
>
> I do things like
>
> - Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention
> - Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them
> - Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted
> - Own suggested edits from anonymous users

Comment: I do know about that, and the most applicable point seems to me to be `Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention`, but both the questions I linked to are not unanswered.

Comment: @Gaffi, a question is considered unanswered for bumping purposes if it doesn't have an answer which has either been upvoted or been accepted.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Well, that makes sense, I suppose, but that's not really clearly stated anywhere, is it? (Did I miss it?)

Comment: @Gaffi, I know I saw it somewhere, but I can't remember now where. Probably a meta post on another stack...

Comment: @Gaffi: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/

Comment: Thanks to both, especially for the link. I can rest easy now. ;-) For the record, I wasn't around SE in '08.

Comment: "Stack Exchange" wasn't around in '08. Just Stack Overflow, and it was an itty bitty little corner of the web at the time.